# What does $|a| = |b|$ is equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I want to know what does $|a| = |b$| is equal to. I think it's equal to $a = \pm b$. Please tell me if I'm right or if I'm wrong.

Comment: This means either $a=b$ or $a=-b$. The informal notation $a=\pm b$ is not really incorrect, but I don't like it too much (what does $a\pm b\pm c$ mean, for instance?)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut As far as I have have been taught $a\pm b\pm c$ means $a+b+c$ or $a-b-c$. $a\pm b\mp c$ means $a+b-c$ or $a-b+c$.

Comment: How can an equation be "equal" to something else?

Comment: It is not *equal to* anything really. With some conventions in place it could evaluate to "True" or "False" depending on the values of $a$ and $b$. For example "|2|=|3|" is equal to "False". However, it is *equivalent to* many other propositions in the two variables $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Sorry, if this sounded nitpicking. I also realize that you may have problems expressing yourself in English. But, it is IMNSHO important to learn the difference between "equal to" and "equivalent to". If only all oour freshmen... back in the day my teacher started hammering this down (relatively gently) in junior high. Now, get off my lawn.

Answer (score 5):

It is equivalent to:

$a=b$ if both are positive or both are negative, or both are zero, and

$a=-b$ if their signs are different.

It means their magnitudes are the same, but not necessarily their signs.

It's important to note that if you restrict yourself to the positive integers then this means $a=b$ as there is no number $-a$ or $-b$ so $\lvert a\rvert = a $ but in the most common high school setting of all real numbers it is as above.

The statement has a more complex meaning in the complex numbers $x=re^{i\theta}$ in which case $\lvert x\rvert=r$, which is again a measure of magnitude with the measure of positive or negative abstracted away.  But in this case rather than the simple $\pm$ being abstracted away, we are removing a more sophisticated measure of the "positiveness" which is $\theta$; a direction vector whose proximity to $\pi$ or $2\pi$ in a sense measures how positive or negative a number is on a circular scale.

Comment: I have to prove if the function x=|y|+3 is injective so I did |a|+3=|b|+3 --> |a|=|b|. So at this point I can say it isn't injective because a could also be equal to -b, right?

Comment: @JonD the answer to that question (is the function injective) is always "NO" if you can find two numbers that the function maps to the same result so yes you basically have it.  In the case of your function $y$ and $-y$ map to the same result.

Comment: @RobertFrost That depends on the domain of the function. If it's not $\Bbb R$ but an adequate interval, the function is injective. A function is not just an expression, you have to consider the domain.

Comment: How can an equation "equal" something else?

Comment: @ZacharySelk equations can be equal e.g. $f(2x)=4x\equiv f(x)=2x$ but I get your point; to talk of such it's important we discriminate different types of equality; usually done via use of the word "equivalent".

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to say that it's equivalent to $$a=b$$ or $$a=-b.$$

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're dealing with. If you're dealing with real numbers, then you're correct: either $a=b$ or $a=-b$ (or both, if $a=b=0$).

If you're dealing with complex numbers, the best you can say is that $a=be^{i\theta}$ for some real $\theta.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider, $$ a^2=b^2$$ which is the same as $$|a|=|b|$$
(Removing even powers results in modulus).

Now $$a^2= b^2 \iff (-a)^2 = a^2 = b^2 = (-b)^2 $$

And that's why, $$|a|=|b| \iff |a|=±b$$ but $$|a|=-b $$ is not possible as modulus of any thing cannot be negative. So $$|a| = b$$

$$ \iff ±a=b $$

$$ \text{OR} \ \ \ \ \ a=b , a=-b \ \ \ \ \  \square $$

I would like to give $ \text{ONE MORE} $ proof.

We have, $$|a|=|b|$$

So, consider the most simple implication,
$$ |a| = ±b \ \ \ \ \text{AND} \ \ \ \ ±a =|b| $$
See, we've used 'AND' but not 'OR' , which means the intersection of both cases.

Proceeding further,

$$ |a|= b \ \ \ \ \text{AND} \ \ \ \ a =|b| $$
$$ ±a = b \ \ \ \ \text{AND} \ \ \ \ a =±b $$
$$ ( a = b \ OR \ -a = b ) \ \ \ \ \text{AND} \ \ \ \ ( a = b \ OR \ -b ) $$
$$ \text{COMBINING BOTH} \ \ \ \ a=b, a=-b$$